# How can I have a HTML form submit by just hitting Enter (no submit button)?

Tags: html, css, forms, submit

I do not want to have a submit button as I want people to be able to enter the form field and then to search all they have to do is press the enter button.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="search">
<div class="search1" form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search"  size="30" value="" 
style="background-color:white; border: 
solid 1px #ffffff; height: 30px; font-size:19px; 
font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light; font-weight: 1;
vertical-align:9px;color:#151515" 
onfocus="if(this.value == ''){this.value = 
'';this.style.color='#363D42'}" />

</div>
<div class="enter"><input type="image" src="but.jpg" alt="Submit"></div>
```

CSS

```
.search {
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid;
color: #BDBDBD;
height: 35px;
width: 270px;
}


.search1 {
margin-top: 3px;
float: left;
}

.enter {
display:none;
}
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: Please edit the first part of the HTML-code for better readability. You do this with using more blanks at the start. Thanks.

Comment: a good practice here is to accept the best answer as a sign of appreciation and to help other users to be able to find the best answer quicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="search1" form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
```

Should be

```
<div class="search1">
<form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the submit button, but style it with:

```
display:none;
```

You also have an error in your syntax:

```
<div class="search1" form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
```

needs to be

```
<div class="search1"> <form action="weezyresults.php" method="post">
```

Good luck !

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! Please check my updated question above, I did what I think would work but it didn't!

Answer (score 0):

write js function and say which will post the form. pseudo code would be

```
 funciton post() 
 {
   if(keycode==13)
     __dopostback();
 }
```

And if you using jquery then, you can use

```
 jquery("form selector").post()
```

Answer (score -2):

Then you should do like this.

```
function formSubmit(element, ev) {
//element is the this selector for current element and ev is the event-trigger to get keycode
if (ev.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is the keycode for Enter-button
    element.form.submit(); //Then submit the button
}
}
```

And add this `onkeypress="submiter(this,event)"` to your input field.

Comment: That's the point. He doesn't want to! - This is not useful and you shouldn't do this, but he want's someting like: `onkeypressed="checkForReturn()"` and then execute `this.form.submit();`.

Comment: I don't want a submit button I just want the text field and once they have entered text int he text field all they have to do is press enter. How is this achieved?

Comment: too hard-codey and non standard.  Anyone else reading the code will be going huh?